# How to get percentage for POST and GET API call by Retrofit 2.1, Just like file upload or download

Tags: android, retrofit2

I want to calculate POST and GET API call percentage in which i am sending json string as request and receiving json response from server .

Also in some api call i am sending form data as key pair as well.

I check these solution which used for showing percentage for file upload [SO upload img](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33338181/is-it-possible-to-show-progress-bar-when-upload-image-via-retrofit-2).

I check similar question here as well [SO](http://SO) but it does not have any answer.

Comment: I did something similar using okhttp using a custom RequestBody subclass.

Comment: @Blackbelt you can post your answer