# Show upload progress with Retrofit & RxJava

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, okhttp

Is it possible to upload a big file using Retrofit + OkHttp and get progress updates using RxJava?

This is the stack im using (RxJava + Retrofit + OkHttp) and it would be lovely to get progress updates in, for instance, onNext().

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44125313/2793134. Code is written in Kotlin , you may have to convert if you want it in Java

Comment: If there is an api you can check for progress status, then yes, you can return the response of that api in onNext() otherwise it would just notify you when upload is complete in onComplete().