# make progress dialog update while uploading image and desciption(for image) using retrofit android

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, progressdialog

I'm trying to create a progress dialog that updates the amount of file updated to server and display them in progress dialog, I followed this post( https://stackoverflow.com/a/33384551 ) the code:

```
  public class ProgressRequestBody extends RequestBody {
    private File mFile;
    private String mPath;
    private UploadCallbacks mListener;

private static final int DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 2048;

public interface UploadCallbacks {
    void onProgressUpdate(int percentage);
    void onError();
    void onFinish();
}

public ProgressRequestBody(final File file, final  UploadCallbacks listener) {
    mFile = file;
    mListener = listener;            
}

@Override
public MediaType contentType() {
    // i want to upload only images
    return MediaType.parse("image/*");
}

@Override
public long contentLength() throws IOException {
  return mFile.length();
}

@Override
public void writeTo(BufferedSink sink) throws IOException {
    long fileLength = mFile.length();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(mFile);
    long uploaded = 0;

    try {
        int read;
        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {

            // update progress on UI thread
            handler.post(new ProgressUpdater(uploaded, fileLength));

            uploaded += read;
            sink.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    } finally {
        in.close();
    }
}

private class ProgressUpdater implements Runnable {
    private long mUploaded;
    private long mTotal;
    public ProgressUpdater(long uploaded, long total) {
        mUploaded = uploaded;
        mTotal = total;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        mListener.onProgressUpdate((int)(100 * mUploaded / mTotal));            
    }
}
}
```

In api interface:

```
 @Multipart
@POST("/upload")        
Call<JsonObject> uploadImage(@Part MultipartBody.Part file);
```

in myActiviy:

```
  class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ProgressRequestBody.UploadCallbacks {
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        ProgressRequestBody fileBody = new ProgressRequestBody(file, this);
        MultipartBody.Part filePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", file.getName(), fileBody);

        Call<JsonObject> request = RetrofitClient.uploadImage(filepart);
        request.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>{...});
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressUpdate(int percentage) {
        // set current progress
        progressBar.setProgress(percentage);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError() {
        // do something on error
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        // do something on upload finished
        // for example start next uploading at queue
        progressBar.setProgress(100);
    }


}
```

The problem I face is when I try to pass the "fileBody" object to

```
  MultipartBody.Part filePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", 
            file.getName(), fileBody);
```

I get an error as filebody cannot be passed in, it's a wrong argument.

I took reference from this post(  https://stackoverflow.com/a/33384551 ) and coded it same but im getting erros.

Answer (score 0):

You missing **file** paramater. Try it

```
File file = new File(your image path);
ProgressRequestBody fileBody = new ProgressRequestBody(file, this);
MultipartBody.Part filePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", file.getName(), fileBody);
```