# upload a file with retrofit and which has a progress bar

Tags: android, upload, progress-bar, retrofit

I wanna upload a file with retrofit which has a progress bar which shows the progress percentage and I wanna send some parameters by post method 
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
first of yore java file in upload pic call in ....progress bar initiation...

-----------------------------------------------------

    SignUp.this.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Call<UploadPhoto> call = apiService.uploadFile(fileToUpload, filename, api, user_email);

            call.enqueue(new Callback<UploadPhoto>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<UploadPhoto> call, Response<UploadPhoto> response) {
                    SignUp.this.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    UploadPhoto inquiryResponse = response.body();
                    if (inquiryResponse.getStatus().equals("1")) {

                    } else {
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<UploadPhoto> call, Throwable t) {
                }
            });


    -----------------------------------------------------------
    and then creat xml file : >> progress_uploading_layout.xml
    --------------------------------------------------------------------
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/uploading"
            android:textColor="@color/green"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    -----------------mention your activity----

    as put your activity_main as xml file ..

            <include layout="@layout/progress_uploading_layout"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Retrofit 2, maybe you could find this answer helpful [Is it possible to show progress bar when upload image via Retrofit 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33338181/is-it-possible-to-show-progress-bar-when-upload-image-via-retrofit-2)