# Regarading retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit2

We are using retrofit2 to make network calls and get our data.

With reference to this link

https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/Callback.html

```
Callback methods are executed using the Retrofit callback executor. When none is specified, the following defaults are used:

Android: Callbacks are executed on the application's main (UI) thread.
JVM: Callbacks are executed on the background thread which performed the request.
```

Now is there any way during a call to execute method to make retrofit2 request we can specify which type of Callback is to be used ?

Thanks

Comment: this might be what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/33384551/7689086

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify what type of callbacks you need to use. Just use regular callback for both cases.

If you want the callback to be executed in the UI thread, just place your code inside the `onResponse` method, otherwise place an `AsyncTask` inside the `onResponse` method.