# Waiting for API Calls to complete with RxJava and Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I'm using RxAndroid and RxJava with Kotlin to make various requests to APIs and reciving them asyncronylusly:

```
    getClient().sendSomeData(data)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(
                    {
                        Log.i("upload", "data ok")
                    },
                    {
                        t ->
                        Log.e("upload", "data error: " + t.stackTrace)
                    }
            );


    getClient().sendSomeOtherData(otherData)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(
                    {
                        Log.i("upload", "otherData ok")
                    },
                    {
                        t ->
                        Log.e("upload", "data error: " + t.stackTrace)
                    }
            );
```

And so on.
What i want to do now is, sort of "wait" for all the api requests to finish and show the progress. How can i wait for all observables to be completed and get a callback with progress?

Comment: You could use deferred objects. Look for JavaScript + Deferred on this site, you should be able to find what you look for.

Answer (score 1):

Answering your first question [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/rxandroid-and-kotlin-part-1-f0382dc26ed8) and [here](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/subscribe.html) you will see mentioned the `Observable.onCompleted` method, which is called after succesful response. Also [here](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#subscribe-rx.functions.Action1-rx.functions.Action1-rx.functions.Action0-) is the doc for the this method. So you could simply implement the third Action in `subscribe` method call and modify your request's state info.

If it comes to the request progress status, I'm not sure, but I suppose that RxJava does not offer this functionality out of the box. However I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33338181/is-it-possible-to-show-progress-bar-when-upload-image-via-retrofit-2/44125313#44125313) (with use of Retrofit library).