# How to show progress with retrofit 2 while uploading?

Tags: android, progress-bar, retrofit2

I am uploading a video to youtube successfully with multipart form data  retrofit 2 .

I want to show progress while uploading. How can I do this ?

Any advice or sample code please ? I searched but couldn't found any solution about this.

when user click the upload button, get token func is calling and video is starting to upload.

**here is my upload func.**

```
public void getToken(final String title) {
    progessBlackView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    showProgressDialog("Loading");
    ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<Token> call = apiService.GETTOKEN(tinyDb.getString(Constant.wkey));
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Token>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Token> call, Response<Token> response) {
            hideProgressDialog();
            if (response != null && response.body() != null) {
                if (response.body().getEx() == null) {
                    String token = response.body().getToken();
                    YouTubeAPIClient.YouTubeAPIService service = YouTubeAPIClient.getClient(token).create(YouTubeAPIClient.YouTubeAPIService.class);
                    JsonObject snippetJson = new JsonObject();
                    snippetJson.addProperty("title", title);
                    snippetJson.addProperty("description", "");
                    JsonObject statusJson = new JsonObject();
                    statusJson.addProperty("privacyStatus", "unlisted");
                    MediaType jsonM = MediaType.parse("application/json");
                    JsonObject partJson = new JsonObject();
                    partJson.add("snippet", snippetJson);
                    partJson.add("status", statusJson);
                    RequestBody part = RequestBody.create(jsonM, partJson.toString());
                    MultipartBody.Part video = prepareFilePart("video", videoFileName);
                    progessBlackView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Call<JsonObject> call2 = service.upload(part, video);
                    call2.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) {
                            if(response.code() == 200){
                                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + response.body());
                                JsonElement tmp = response.body().get("id");
                                if(tmp  != null) {
                                    String vkey = tmp.toString();
                                    vkey = vkey.replace("\"","");
                                    String item = "";
                                    for (int i = 0; i < mtagIds.size(); i++) {
                                        item = item + mtagIds.get(i);
                                        if (i != mtagIds.size() - 1) {
                                            item = item + ", ";
                                        }
                                    }
                                    String videoKey = vkey.toString();
                                    JoinAllAllowedInno selectedJoin = DataHolder.getInstance().getSelectedJoin();
                                    addVideo(selectedJoin.getInnoId(), videoKey, title, item);
                                }
                                else {
                                    getAlertError((String) getText(R.string.videoNotFound));
                                }
                                progessBlackView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable t) {
                            Log.i("YoutubeUpload", t.getMessage());
                            getAlertError((String) getText(R.string.videoNotFound));
                            progessBlackView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    });

                } else {
                    getAlertError(response.body().getEx());
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Token> call, Throwable t) {
            hideProgressDialog();
            Log.e(CLASS_NAME, t.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to show progress bar when upload image via Retrofit 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33338181/is-it-possible-to-show-progress-bar-when-upload-image-via-retrofit-2)

Comment: Good example here : https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-download-files-with-progress-updates

Comment: I think your question was answered in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33338181/is-it-possible-to-show-progress-bar-when-upload-image-via-retrofit-2