# Show progress while uploading multipart file using retrofit

Tags: android

Hello everyone i am uploading multipal files to server and file are uploading successfully .i want to get progress percentage while uploading here is my code

```
    ArrayList<SelectedFiles> selectedfiles = new ArrayList<>();


 private void UploadFilestoServer() {
    CustomUtils.ShowProgress(this);
    MultipartBody.Builder builder = new MultipartBody.Builder();
    builder.setType(MultipartBody.FORM);
    Call<ResponseBody> call = null;
    builder.addFormDataPart("email", user_mail);
    for (int i = 0; i < selectedfiles.size(); i++) {
        File file = new File(selectedfiles.get(i).getFilepath());
        builder.addFormDataPart("file[]", file.getName(), RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file));

        MultipartBody requestBody = builder.build();
        call = service.uploadFile(requestBody);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                CustomUtils.HideProgressDialog();
                finish();

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                CustomUtils.HideProgressDialog();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: do you want to show this progress in terms of number of files ? or the amount of data being uploaded ?

Comment: follow this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/33384551/7348352

Comment: amount of data to be uploaded