# How to measure upload progress of a huge String with Retrofit 2?

Tags: android, rest, http-post, retrofit2, okhttp

I use Retrofit 2 and a **POST** Rest call to send some data to backend. My rest interface looks like:

```
void postSpecialData(String base64, Callback callback);
```

whereas my Callback is Retrofit interface with:

```
  void onResponse(Call<T> call, Response<T> response);
  void onFailure(Call<T> call, Throwable t);
```

I call then finally:

```
getRestCommunicator().postSpecialData(encryptedBase64, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {
                toast("Response code " + response.code());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {
                toast("Failure REST CALL");
            }
});
```

The encryptedBase64 variable is neither a File nor stored somewhere.
**How can I get the upload progress to make it visible on a progress bar for example?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33338181/is-it-possible-to-show-progress-bar-when-upload-image-via-retrofit-2): Extend OkHttp3's RequestBody and overwrite `writeTo(BufferedSink sink)` for String `yourHugeString` instead of a file:

```
@Override
    public void writeTo(BufferedSink sink) throws IOException {
        StringReader in = new StringReader(yourHugeString);
        char[] buffer = new char[2048]; // you can modifiy the buffer
        try {
            int read;
            while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                sink.write(new String(buffer).getBytes(), 0, read);
                mListener.onProgressUpdate(read);
            }
        } finally {
            in.close();
            mListener.onFinish(uploaded);
        }
}
```

whereas `yourHugeString` is your string variable with very huge string content. I converted for `write()` to String, because, the `read()` requires `char[]` whereas `write()` --> `byte[]`

Then just modify your interface:

```
void postSpecialData(SpecialRequestBody base64, Callback callback);
```