# Why do I get IndexOutOfBoundsException in StringReader read()?

Tags: android, retrofit2, indexoutofboundsexception, okhttp, stringreader

As [in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33338181/is-it-possible-to-show-progress-bar-when-upload-image-via-retrofit-2), I want to measure my upload progress, but not for an image, for a simple `base64` String instead. That String is usually approx. 500 kB length.

As in the example I extended the Body from OkHttp3's `RequestBody` and overwrote:

```
@Override
    public void writeTo(BufferedSink sink) throws IOException {
        StringReader in = new StringReader(base64);
        char[] buffer = new char[2048];
        int uploaded = 0;
        try {
            int read;
            while ((read = in.read(buffer, uploaded, buffer.length)) != -1) {
                uploaded += read;
                System.out.println("BUFFER " + buffer);
                sink.write(new String(buffer).getBytes(), 0, read);
                this.callback.onProgressUpdate(uploaded);
            }
        } catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.err.println("IndexOutOfBoundsException uploaded " + uploaded + " , buffer " + buffer.length + " from total " + base64.length());
        } finally {
            in.close();
            this.callback.onFinish(uploaded);
        }
}
```

I can read the first 2048 chars successsfully, but for the second round in while-loop I get a `IndexOutOfBoundsException` ?

Comment: can you provide in which line does the exception is thrown? (remove catch block)

Comment: in `in.read` use `0` as an offset (second parameter) and in `sink.write` use `buffer` as a first parameter

Comment: @maheryhaja the read() in the while

Comment: @pskink the read() in while() required a char[] whereas the write() requires a byte[]

Comment: so just use `0` in `in.read`

Comment: The  offset in `read()`relates to buffer. So it should be 0 .. Then I'd rather use `in.read(buffer)`..