# I want show upload percent

Tags: java, android, file-upload, progress-bar

I have an app that users can upload file. Right now it works.
They can upload files and it received in server side.
Now I want show upload percent to users while uploading.
I used below code to upload files on server.

here is my java code:

```
        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try{
                    new MaterialFilePicker().
                            withActivity(AddActivity.this).
                            withRequestCode(10).
                            start();


                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
```

and this is my method:

ProgressDialog progress;

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    if (requestCode==10 && resultCode==RESULT_OK){


        progress = new ProgressDialog(AddActivity.this);
        progress.setTitle("Uploading");
        progress.setMessage("please wait...");
        progress.show();


        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                File f = new File(data.getStringExtra(FilePickerActivity.RESULT_FILE_PATH));
                String content_type = getMimeType(f.getPath());
                String file_path = f.getAbsolutePath();

                file_size = String.valueOf(f.length()/1024);

                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                RequestBody file_body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(content_type),f);

                RequestBody request_body = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                        .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                        .addFormDataPart("type",content_type)
                        .addFormDataPart("upload_file",code+file_path.substring(file_path.lastIndexOf(".")),file_body)
                        .build();

                code2 = code+file_path.substring(file_path.lastIndexOf("."));

                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url("http://api.mysite.com/api/uploadfile")
                        .post(request_body)
                        .build();

                try {
                    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

                    Log.d("msg",request_body.toString());
                    Log.d("msg",f.getPath().toString());
                    Log.d("msg",getMimeType(f.getPath()));
                    Log.d("msg33",code+file_path.substring(file_path.lastIndexOf(".")));

                    if (!response.isSuccessful()){
                        throw new IOException(("Error:"+response));
                    }
                    progress.dismiss();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }


        });
        t.start();
    }
}
```

Please help me to add upload percentage.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a lot of things wrong here:

1. Logic responsible for uploading file should not be located in `onActivityResult()`
2. You should seperate it into different method
3. Using thread like that is not a good idea

If you want to upload file or large file you should do it in `IntentService` class (You will have to create Your own class and extend `IntentService`), it is something that is meant for things like that. I suggest You to learn about Retrofit2 and OkHttp library cause it will make it a lot of easier.

An example where you can find a one of the ways how to do it is here: [Is it possible to show progress bar when upload image via Retrofit 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33338181/is-it-possible-to-show-progress-bar-when-upload-image-via-retrofit-2)

Asking ppl at stackoverflow to write code completly for you is not a good way to improve your skills. Check this link which I gave You.

Good luck

**EDIT:**

Android Services: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html and https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service

Retrofit 2: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html

OkHttp: https://www.journaldev.com/13629/okhttp-android-example-tutorial

Sample: [Is it possible to show progress bar when upload image via Retrofit 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33338181/is-it-possible-to-show-progress-bar-when-upload-image-via-retrofit-2)

These link provides all the information You need in order to write this functionality. I don't have videos on YouTube with things like this. I'm never using YouTube to get this kind of information.

Comment: Thanks for your attention and your guidance. But I did not ask to write code for me. I did post my codes here and want to get help to locate progress bar on it.
If I knew how should implement that , I never ask for help.
I even did not knew that my solution is not a good idea and if I didn't ask and you didn't answer I will remain in wrong way.
I really thank you for you respond but I'm not a lazy man.
I work on my code in Iran with all limits to access the sources. I just expect RESPECT.
Thank you.

Comment: I gave You all needed information to write code which You need to write. The only thing left to do is to read it and enter this link.

Comment: Yes, I thank you. And I'm trying to edit my code in order to your answer. Thanks a lot. I just said want respect.

Comment: Dawid Jamroży, hello. can you introduce me some sources or youtube video about it?