# Show upload image progress Multipart

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, multipart, coroutine

In Fragment B, I have a submit button used to submit image to server. When submit button is clicked, it will return to Fragment A. I using `Multipart` to upload image to server, and the process is running on `Thread` so user can do other task while waiting image to upload.

**Fragment B** (when submit button is clicked)

```
 inner class SimpleThread() :Thread() {
            override fun run() {
                for (i in newList!!) {
                    val service = RetrofitFactory.makeRetrofitService()
                    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                        val request2 = WebApi.createImage(
                            activity,File(i)
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
```

**WebApi**

```
suspend fun createImage(
        file: File?
    ): WebApiResponse.Image? {
        val image = file?.let {
            MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(
                "image",
                it.getName(),
                RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), it)
            )
        }

        return RetrofitFactory.apiCall(context) {
            RetrofitFactory.makeRetrofitService().submitImages(
              image
            )
        }
    }
```

**RetrofitService**

```
@Multipart
    @POST("create_image")
    fun submitImages(
        @Part image: MultipartBody.Part?
    ): Deferred<Response<WebApiResponse.Image>>
```

I am able to upload image to server, but how can I show a upload image progress on Fragment A ?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33338181/is-it-possible-to-show-progress-bar-when-upload-image-via-retrofit-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so after just a little bit of research I found two ways for you

1- if you are using `RxJava` I would suggest to follow the instructions and cautions in this link 
[display progress of multipart with retrofit using RxJava](https://medium.com/@PaulinaSadowska/display-progress-of-multipart-request-with-retrofit-and-rxjava-23a4a779e6ba)

2- if you are not using `RxJava` add a `ProgressResponseBody` to the retrofit builder that would look something like this:

```
public class ProgressRequestBody extends RequestBody {
private File mFile;
private String mPath;
private UploadCallbacks mListener;
private String content_type;

private static final int DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 2048;

public interface UploadCallbacks {
    void onProgressUpdate(int percentage);
    void onError();
    void onFinish();
}
```

for this one you should use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33338181/is-it-possible-to-show-progress-bar-when-upload-image-via-retrofit-2)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use WorkManaget or IntenService for showing the progress.
[A sample to send via retrofit2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33338181/is-it-possible-to-show-progress-bar-when-upload-image-via-retrofit-2)
You can start the process in service. The service can send a new event.

Answer (score -1):

Custom RequestBody

```
    public class FileProgressRequestBody extends RequestBody {

        public interface ProgressListener {
            void transferred(int size);
        }
        private RequestBody mRequestBody;

        protected ProgressListener listener;

        public FileProgressRequestBody(File file, String contentType, ProgressListener listener) {
            this.mRequestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(contentType), file);
            this.listener = listener;
        }

        @Override
        public long contentLength() throws IOException{
            return mRequestBody.contentLength();
        }

        @Override
        public MediaType contentType() {
            return mRequestBody.contentType();
        }

        @Override
        public void writeTo(@NonNull BufferedSink sink) throws IOException {
            if (sink instanceof Buffer) {
                // Log Interceptor
                mRequestBody.writeTo(sink);
                return;
            }
            CountingSink countingSink = new CountingSink(sink);
            BufferedSink bufferedSink = Okio.buffer(countingSink);
            mRequestBody.writeTo(bufferedSink);
            bufferedSink.flush();
        }

        protected final class CountingSink extends ForwardingSink {
            private long bytesWritten = 0;

            public CountingSink(Sink delegate) {
                super(delegate);
            }

            @Override
            public void write(@NonNull Buffer source, long byteCount) throws IOException {
                super.write(source, byteCount);
                bytesWritten += byteCount;
                if (listener != null) {
                    long length = contentLength();
                    if (length != 0) {
                        listener.transferred(MathUtils.clamp((int) (bytesWritten * 100 / length), 0, 100));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

use `MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", file.getName(), new FileProgressRequestBody(file, "image/*", youListener));`

Comment: EventBus and so on.

Comment: what is `youListener` in your last comment ?

Comment: the progress in `transferred` show 100 but my image still uploading