# How to upload base64 json body with progress percent in Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2, progressdialog

i'm converting pdf file to base64 before uploading to server ,how can i show progress bar with percentage while uploading json body to server

here is my upload interface

```
@POST("promoter/upload_cv")
Call<Void> postCv( @Body CvModel cvModel, @Header("client") String clientId, @Header("access-token") String accessToken)
```

and the CvModel class

```
public class CvModel {

    @SerializedName("cv")
    @Expose
    private String cv;
    @SerializedName("cv_name")
    @Expose
    private String cvName;

    public String getCv() {
        return cv;
    }

    public void setCv(String cv) {
        this.cv = cv;
    }

    public String getCvName() {
        return cvName;
    }

    public void setCvName(String cvName) {
        this.cvName = cvName;
    }

}
```

Comment: maybe duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33338181/is-it-possible-to-show-progress-bar-when-upload-image-via-retrofit-2

Comment: i checked it but it's explaining uploading file not json

Comment: Its doesnt metter what are you sending. Use sample from here <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33338181/is-it-possible-to-show-progress-bar-when-upload-image-via-retrofit-2>