# How to get upload progress percentage in retrofit mulitpart request?

Tags: android, rest, retrofit2, retrofit2.6

*Following is the multipart request that i am performing using **`retrofit2`**.*
What i want is to somehow get a callback of the `upload percentage`. *But i cannot a find a suitable method for doing this. I have saw few methods but they are only playing with `single` file.* ***What i want is to achieve is get a upload progress percentage of combine all files sent in the request.***

```
    @Multipart
    @POST("post/vehicle/detail")
    Call<SuccessModel> uploadVehicle(

            @Part("user_id") int userId,
            @Part("name") String vehicleName,
            @Part("number") int stockNumber,
            @Part MultipartBody.Part mainImage,
            @Part MultipartBody.Part hoodsImage,
            @Part MultipartBody.Part bumperImage,
            @Part MultipartBody.Part interiorImage,
            @Part MultipartBody.Part frontSeatImage,
            @Part MultipartBody.Part backSeatImage,
            @Part MultipartBody.Part dashboardImage,
            @Part MultipartBody.Part headLampsImage,
            @Part MultipartBody.Part tailLightsImage,
            @Part MultipartBody.Part backEngineImage
    );
```

***Edit***

***Some more code about How i am creating Request.***

```
File mainImage = new File(vehicleEntity.mainImage);

            RequestBody requestMainFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), mainImage);

            MultipartBody.Part main = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("main_image", mainImage.getName(), requestMainFile);

            File hoodImage, bumperImage, interiorImage, frontSeatImage, backSeatImage, dashboardImage, headLampsImage, tailLightImage, backEngineImage;

            MultipartBody.Part hood = null, bumper = null, interior = null, frontSeat = null, backSeat = null, dashboard = null, headLamps = null, tailLights = null, backEngine = null;

            if (vehicleEntity.hoodsImage != null) {

                hoodImage = new File(vehicleEntity.hoodsImage);
                RequestBody requestHoodFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), hoodImage);
                hood = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("hoods", hoodImage.getName(), requestHoodFile);

            }

            if (vehicleEntity.bumperImage != null) {

                bumperImage = new File(vehicleEntity.bumperImage);
                RequestBody requestBumperFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), bumperImage);
                bumper = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("bumpers", mainImage.getName(), requestBumperFile);

            }

            if (vehicleEntity.interiorImage != null) {

                interiorImage = new File(vehicleEntity.interiorImage);
                RequestBody requestInteriorFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), interiorImage);
                interior = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("interiors", mainImage.getName(), requestInteriorFile);

            }

            if (vehicleEntity.frontSeatImage != null) {

                frontSeatImage = new File(vehicleEntity.frontSeatImage);
                RequestBody requestFrontSeatFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), frontSeatImage);
                frontSeat = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("front_seat", mainImage.getName(), requestFrontSeatFile);

            }

            if (vehicleEntity.backSeatImage != null) {

                backSeatImage = new File(vehicleEntity.backSeatImage);
                RequestBody requestBackSeatFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), backSeatImage);
                backSeat = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("back_seat", mainImage.getName(), requestBackSeatFile);

            }

            if (vehicleEntity.dashboardImage != null) {

                dashboardImage = new File(vehicleEntity.dashboardImage);
                RequestBody requestDashboardFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), dashboardImage);
                dashboard = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("dashboard", mainImage.getName(), requestDashboardFile);

            }

            if (vehicleEntity.headLampsImage != null) {

                headLampsImage = new File(vehicleEntity.headLampsImage);
                RequestBody requestHeadLampsFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), headLampsImage);
                headLamps = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("headlamps", mainImage.getName(), requestHeadLampsFile);

            }

            if (vehicleEntity.tailLightsImage != null) {

                tailLightImage = new File(vehicleEntity.tailLightsImage);
                RequestBody requestTailsLightFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), tailLightImage);
                tailLights = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("tail_light", mainImage.getName(), requestTailsLightFile);

            }

            if (vehicleEntity.backEngineImage != null) {

                backEngineImage = new File(vehicleEntity.backEngineImage);
                RequestBody requestBackEngineFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), backEngineImage);
                backEngine = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("tail_light", mainImage.getName(), requestBackEngineFile);

            }


            int userId = Integer.parseInt(sharedPreferences.getString(USER_ID, null));

            String vehicleName = vehicleEntity.vehicleName;

            int stockNumber = Integer.parseInt(vehicleEntity.stockNumber);

            Call<SuccessModel> call = apiInterface.uploadVehicle(

                    userId, vehicleName, stockNumber, main,
                    hood, bumper, interior, frontSeat, backSeat,
                    dashboard, headLamps, tailLights, backEngine

            );
```

Comment: BTW have you tried this?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33384551/8663316

Comment: @FaizanHaidarKhan How to get combine progress of multiple files using this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33338181/is-it-possible-to-show-progress-bar-when-upload-image-via-retrofit-2/33384551#33384551

Comment: Get the network speed  at each moment and show the total by multiplying