# PublishSubject with Kotlin coroutines (Flow/Channel)

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines

I'm uploading files with retrofit. I want to listen to the retrofit progress in Kotlin and show it with the progress bar on ui. When I did research on this, I found a good example of this in java using PublishSubject on this page. [Is it possible to show progress bar when upload image via Retrofit 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33338181/is-it-possible-to-show-progress-bar-when-upload-image-via-retrofit-2)
I want to adapt this to my own code, but I can't decide whether I should use Flow or Channel instead of PublishSubject in Kotlin.

My requestbody class with broadcastChannel:

```
class ProgressRequestBody : RequestBody {
    val mFile: File
    val ignoreFirstNumberOfWriteToCalls : Int

    constructor(mFile: File) : super(){
        this.mFile = mFile
        ignoreFirstNumberOfWriteToCalls = 0
    }

    constructor(mFile: File, ignoreFirstNumberOfWriteToCalls : Int) : super(){
        this.mFile = mFile
        this.ignoreFirstNumberOfWriteToCalls = ignoreFirstNumberOfWriteToCalls
    }
    var numWriteToCalls = 0

    val getProgress = BroadcastChannel<Float>(1)


    override fun contentType(): MediaType? {
        return "image/*".toMediaTypeOrNull()
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun contentLength(): Long {
        return mFile.length()
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun writeTo(sink: BufferedSink) {
        numWriteToCalls++

        val fileLength = mFile.length()
        val buffer = ByteArray(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE)
        val `in` = FileInputStream(mFile)
        var uploaded: Long = 0

        try {
            var read: Int
            var lastProgressPercentUpdate = 0.0f
            read = `in`.read(buffer)
            while (read != -1) {

                uploaded += read.toLong()
                sink.write(buffer, 0, read)
                read = `in`.read(buffer)

                // when using HttpLoggingInterceptor it calls writeTo and passes data into a local buffer just for logging purposes.
                // the second call to write to is the progress we actually want to track
                if (numWriteToCalls > ignoreFirstNumberOfWriteToCalls ) {
                    val progress = (uploaded.toFloat() / fileLength.toFloat()) * 100f
                    //prevent publishing too many updates, which slows upload, by checking if the upload has progressed by at least 1 percent
                    if (progress - lastProgressPercentUpdate > 1 || progress == 100f) {
                        // publish progress
                        getProgress.send(progress)
                        lastProgressPercentUpdate = progress
                    }
                }
            }
        } finally {
            `in`.close()
        }
    }


    companion object {

        private val DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 2048
    }
}
```

The problem is that `broadcastChannel.send(progress)` wants the function to suspend but the RequestBody `writeTo` method should not suspend. In this case, I am confused. Should I use Flow or BroadCastChannel? Can you help me?

Comment: If you're on JVM or Android, you should be able to use `sendBlocking()` instead of `send()`, which does not suspend (but blocks the current thread). Note that you always have the option to use `runBlocking` in situations where you are bridging blocking code with suspending code (again, only on the JVM)

Comment: [StateFlow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-state-flow/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```kotlin
val getProgress = MutableSharedFlow<Float>(extraBufferCapacity = 1)

getProgress.tryEmit(progress)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply this solved my problem

Answer (score 3):

You should use MutableStateFlow:

```
val getProgress = MutableStateFlow<Float>(0f) // Initial value is 0
```

Then:

```
getProgress.value = progress
```

See more: [StateFlow and SharedFlow](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow/stateflow-and-sharedflow)