# Content resolver returns wrong size

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

I am picking an image from the gallery and querying its size via `ContentResolver` API, it returns 29kb.

However when I check the file via adb using `ls -al` it is 44kb

here is how I query the size of the image:

```
    private fun getFileInfo(contentResolver: ContentResolver, fileUri: Uri): Pair<String, Long>? {
    val projection = arrayOf(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE)
    val metaCursor = contentResolver.query(fileUri, projection, null, null, null)
        metaCursor?.use {
            if (it.moveToFirst()) {
                val displayNameIndex = it.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)
                val sizeIndex = it.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE)
                return Pair(it.getString(displayNameIndex), it.getLong(sizeIndex))
            }
    }
    return null
}
```

I am using an Oreo Emulator.
I have also checked via emulator's tools, file browser shows as 29kb on the other hand file details shows 45kb.
What is going on?

Here are the images from file browser:

[image: Summary]

[image: Details]

Another side note, above situation can be reproducible every time when using camera app on emulator with Android 26-Oreo emulator, however it is fine with emulator Android 25-Nougat.

I have checked, new [Document API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/provider/DocumentFile.html) also returns 29kb

Comment: Did you tried to force media store to rescan? Maybe size was changed and it is not updated in the database

Comment: @Selvin It is a Google API emulator, so cannot run root commands, but restarted the emulator.

Comment: root commands? I'm pretty sure that `Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE` doesn't need root

Comment: @Selvin I have tried after your comment, not helping.

Comment: Is it not because one is the real size of the file, and the other one the space occupied by the file on the storage?

Comment: @Eselfar is it so different as 29kb vs 45kb?
Secondly why and how it is changed on Oreo?
I am asking from content provider to give me a stream and a size. Where is the logic on that if size does not match with stream length...

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue. The ContentResolver was underestimating the true filesize by about 400 bytes. I solved it using a similar approach to that explained in [How to correctly get the file size of an android.net.Uri?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21882322/how-to-correctly-get-the-file-size-of-an-android-net-uri) :

```
ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(imageUri, "r");
fileLength = pfd.getStatSize();
pfd.close();
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using it inside a loop. When I used this function in a loop with 10000 objects, it caused a delay of about 10-20 seconds.

Answer (score -1):

Android 8.0 (Oreo) introduced the 'SDCardFS' filesystem, which replaced 'FUSE' on the /sdcard partition.

it is possible that this new filesystem has a large cluster size and is therefore not able to allocate exactly 29kb, but instead the smallest block larger than 29kb, which in your case is 44.*kb.

The difference between `ls -al` and file details is probably caused by different rounding.

Comment: I doubt if that is the case. I have took several shots; when an image showed 35kb, details showed 53kb on the same emulator.

And side note, 8.1 Emulator also returns different values, however difference is much more small.

Comment: @guness, does this only happen on images? have you tried different image formats? EDIT: sometimes the filesystem doesn't deallocate space after the file has shrunk, causing fragmentation, this also might be the case if you've edited the file a bunch.

Comment: Videos seems to be fine, and I haven't edited images ever. Lastly Camera takes images in one format only: jpg

Edit: I believe this is related to following question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21882322/how-to-correctly-get-the-file-size-of-an-android-net-uri