# Get file size using URI in android

Tags: android, file, video, uri

I am working on android video application where I am recording a Video using Camera Intent and taking a video from gallery. When recording video or after selecting video from gallery I want to know the size of my video which I took. I want to make a logic to show a user a toast message if selected Video size is greater then 5MB.
I made the bottom logic which is not working and giving me 0 value where I tried to take the size from URI.

Thanks in advance.

My Logic which is not working

```
java.net.URI juri = new java.net.URI(uri.toString());
        File mediaFile = new File(juri.getPath());
        long fileSizeInBytes = mediaFile.length();
        long fileSizeInKB = fileSizeInBytes / 1024;
        long fileSizeInMB = fileSizeInKB / 1024;

        if (fileSizeInMB > 5) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Video files lesser than 5MB are allowed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
```

This is my code which I am using to get video from Gallery and to record video.

```
public void takeVideoFromCamera(){

        File mediaFile =new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+ "/myvideo.mp4");

        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        Uri videoUri;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
//            videoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", mediaFile);
            videoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "i.am.ce.by.ncy.provider", mediaFile);
        } else {
            videoUri  = Uri.fromFile(mediaFile);
        }
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, videoUri);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT, 5491520L);//5*1048*1048=5MB
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT,45);
        startActivityForResult(intent, VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    }

    public void takeVideoFromGallery(){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("video/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        long maxVideoSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MB
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT, maxVideoSize);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Video"),REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_VIDEO);

    }
```

onActivityResult code

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == this.RESULT_OK) {

            switch (requestCode) {
                case VIDEO_CAPTURE:
                        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                            showVideoImage(data.getData());
// Here I want to know what is the size of my Video File
                        } 
                    break;
                case REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_VIDEO:
                    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                        showVideoGallery(data);
// Here I want to know what is the size of my Video File
                    } 
                    break;
          }
```

Answer (score 15):

```
AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(uri , "r");
long fileSize = fileDescriptor.getLength();
```

Comment: I think it gets stream from ContentProvider registered for the uri and asks stream what its length.

Comment: This is amazingly easy and effective.  I worry this meta length may not always match actually read data length from stream, but this is still an incredibly useful metric to check on this type of URI, thank you.

Answer (score 10):

1. Checks `AssetFileDescriptor.length`
2. If not found, checks `ParcelFileDescriptor.getStatSize` implicitly inside `AssetFileDescriptor.length`
3. If not found, check `MediaStore/ContentResolver` if URI has `content://` scheme

Should work for `file://`, `content://` schemes. Returns `-1L` if failed to find:

```
fun Uri.length(contentResolver: ContentResolver)
        : Long {

    val assetFileDescriptor = try {
        contentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(this, "r")
    } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
        null
    }
    // uses ParcelFileDescriptor#getStatSize underneath if failed
    val length = assetFileDescriptor?.use { it.length } ?: -1L
    if (length != -1L) {
        return length
    }

    // if "content://" uri scheme, try contentResolver table
    if (scheme.equals(ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT)) {
        return contentResolver.query(this, arrayOf(OpenableColumns.SIZE), null, null, null)
                ?.use { cursor ->
                    // maybe shouldn't trust ContentResolver for size: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48302972/content-resolver-returns-wrong-size
                    val sizeIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE)
                    if (sizeIndex == -1) {
                        return@use -1L
                    }
                    cursor.moveToFirst()
                    return try {
                        cursor.getLong(sizeIndex)
                    } catch (_: Throwable) {
                        -1L
                    }
                } ?: -1L
    } else {
        return -1L
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
java.net.URI juri = new java.net.URI(uri.toString());
File mediaFile = new File(juri.getPath());
```

A `Uri` is not a `File`.

```
showVideoImage(data.getData());
```

[`ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE` does not return a `Uri`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE).

Moreover, **you already know where the file is**. You create a `File` object in `takeVideoFromCamera()` and use that for `EXTRA_OUTPUT`. Hold onto that `File` object (and also save it in the saved instance state `Bundle`), then use that for finding out the size of the resulting video.

Comment: thanks for your answer and this good explanation. Can you please give me a code snippet in my above code example. It will be really helpful for me.

Comment: @CommonWare basically I want to know the resulted Video size in both scenarios, like for takeVideoFromCamera() and for takeVideoFromGallery(). Thanks

Comment: @UKhan: [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.10/Media/VideoRecordIntent) demonstrates using `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE` with `FileProvider`. I show how to hold onto the `File` and the `Uri` in fields. In my case, I happen to use the `Uri` in `onActivityResult()`, whereas you would use the `File`.

Answer (score 3):

Following extension function supports 3 different URI types,

1. Content URI `content://document/primary:sample.png`
2. File URI `file://data/user/0/com.example.testapp/cache/output.png`
3. Resource URI `"android.resource://com.example.testapp/" + R.raw.sample`

```
fun Uri.length(context: Context): Long {
    val fromContentProviderColumn = fun(): Long {
        // Try to get content length from the content provider column OpenableColumns.SIZE
        // which is recommended to implement by all the content providers
        var cursor: Cursor? = null
        return try {
            cursor = context.contentResolver.query(
                this,
                arrayOf(OpenableColumns.SIZE),
                null,
                null,
                null
            ) ?: throw Exception("Content provider returned null or crashed")
            val sizeColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE)
            if (sizeColumnIndex != -1 && cursor.count > 0) {
                cursor.moveToFirst()
                cursor.getLong(sizeColumnIndex)
            } else {
                -1
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.message ?: e.javaClass.simpleName)
            -1
        } finally {
            cursor?.close()
        }
    }

    val fromFileDescriptor = fun(): Long {
        // Try to get content length from content scheme uri or file scheme uri
        var fileDescriptor: ParcelFileDescriptor? = null
        return try {
            fileDescriptor = context.contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(this, "r")
                ?: throw Exception("Content provider recently crashed")
            fileDescriptor.statSize
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.message ?: e.javaClass.simpleName)
            -1
        } finally {
            fileDescriptor?.close()
        }
    }

    val fromAssetFileDescriptor = fun(): Long {
        // Try to get content length from content scheme uri, file scheme uri or android resource scheme uri
        var assetFileDescriptor: AssetFileDescriptor? = null
        return try {
            assetFileDescriptor = context.contentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(this, "r")
                ?: throw Exception("Content provider recently crashed")
            assetFileDescriptor.length
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.message ?: e.javaClass.simpleName)
            -1
        } finally {
            assetFileDescriptor?.close()
        }
    }

    return when (scheme) {
        ContentResolver.SCHEME_FILE -> {
            fromFileDescriptor()
        }
        ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT -> {
            val length = fromContentProviderColumn()
            if (length >= 0) {
                length
            } else {
                fromFileDescriptor()
            }
        }
        ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE -> {
            fromAssetFileDescriptor()
        }
        else -> {
            -1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: not working in `Oreo` and below

Answer (score 0):

```
private long getFileSize(Uri fileUri) {
    Cursor returnCursor = getContentResolver().
            query(fileUri, null, null, null, null);
    int sizeIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE);
    returnCursor.moveToFirst();
    
    long size = returnCursor.getLong(sizeIndex);
    returnCursor.close();

    return size;
}
```

Check [here](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/retrieve-info) for more details

Comment: You should close cursor to release resources.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
        Uri path = data.getData();
        Cursor returnCursor = getContentResolver().
                query(path, null, null, null, null);
        int sizeIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE);
        returnCursor.moveToFirst();

        int size = returnCursor.getInt(sizeIndex) / 1000;

        returnCursor.close();

        tv_description.setText("size: " + size);
```

You Can use getInt, getLong etc...

Answer (score -4):

try this

> File file = new File(URI);

```
    if (file.exists()){
        long size = file.length();
    }
```

the value is = 0 when

the file exists but contained zero bytes.
the file does not exist, or
the file is some OS-specific special file.